# I don't get the title using FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever

Tags: android, ffmpeg, metadata, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to fetch the title of a streaming song and I am using the FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever library but it doesn't seem to be working

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
        mmr.setDataSource("http://167.114.64.181:9407/stream");

        nowPlaying =  mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);

        nowPlayingtxt.setText(nowPlaying);
        mmr.release();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this.

```
private Runnable hMyTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
        mmr.setDataSource("your mp3 url");
        FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.Metadata md = mmr.getMetadata();
        HashMap<String, String> map = md.getAll();
        String valor = map.get("StreamTitle");
        textView3.setText(valor);
    }
};
```